# C++ pointer to member function

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Object{
int foo(int *a){return 0;}
};

int main(){

int (Object::**p1)(int *) = &Object::foo;

int (Object::*&p2)(int *) = *Object::foo;

}
```

I've been trying to figure this out but I can't seem to get it debugged.

"invalid initialization" for the second line.

Comment: Only the second line?

Comment: "The second line" -- you mean `using namespace std;`? Line numbering kinda matters here...

Comment: sorry, I mean the int (Object::*&p)(int *) = *Object::foo line as well as the previous one.

Comment: Your declarations, apart from having the wrong return type, seem to think `Object::foo` is a pointer.

Comment: Ah, I just changed the return value of the int foo(int*a) function, as it wasn't returning the same value as the pointers to member functions I've defined.  Here are the errors:cannot convert ‘int (Object::*)(int*)’ to ‘int (Object::**)(int*)’ in initialization
error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘int Object::foo(int*)’

Comment: @user3250551, The first error is perfectly clear. `&Object::foo` is an `int *(Object::*)(int *)`, not an `int *(Object::**)(int *)`. The second refers to it not being a pointer, or some other thing you can dereference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lines will not compile.

1. `&Object::foo` takes the address of a member function, giving you a pointer to the member function. It's type is `int (Object::*)(int*)`, so the type of `p1` has to match.
2. `*Object::foo` attempts to perform indirection on the member function, which is simply not something you can do. Indirection is something you perform on pointers.

Note that the type you've given for `p2` is a reference to a pointer to member function, so it will not bind to a temporary. You could, for example, do this instead:

```
int (Object::*p1)(int *) = &Object::foo;
int (Object::*&p2)(int *) = p1;
```

Comment: This works well for **&p2, but I'm still unsure as to how to define a double pointer Object::**p1(int*) = &&Object::foo??

Comment: I realized it's just = &p1.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3250551 You might also want to have a look at my answer. It should give you some additional insight.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with references to member function pointers the easiest way is to introduce an appropriate typedefs IMHO:

```
struct Object {
   int foo(int *a) { return 0; }
   int bar(int *a) { return 1; }
};

typedef int (Object::*ObjFPtrType)(int *);
typedef int (Object::*&ObjFPtrTypeRef)(int *);

void setFnPtr(ObjFPtrType* p) {
    *p = &Object::foo;
}

void setFnPtrRef(ObjFPtrTypeRef r) {
    r = &Object::bar;
}

int main() {

    ObjFPtrType p1 = 0;
    setFnPtr(&p1);

    ObjFPtrTypeRef p2 = p1;
    setFnPtrRef(p2);
}
```

While I was trying to write and improve this answer, I also stumbled over the fact that `ObjFPtrTypeRef` isn't equivalent to `ObjFPtrType&`, but forms it's own type.
The above sample compiles fine and was proven with [GCC 4.8.2 on ideone](http://ideone.com/CnxHon).